# Access DbPropertyValues ComplexTypes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the current `DbPropertyValues` values and I want to trim all values before saving them.

I can get all string values. But I have problems when I want to access a complex type of let's say "Car".

This works:

```cs
var propertyNames = values.PropertyNames.Where(p => currentValues[p] is string);
foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames) // trim
```

This does not work (and is actually empty):

```cs
var propertyNames = values.PropertyNames.Where(p => currentValues[p] is Car);
foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames) // trim
```

This does not work (and returns `DbPropertyValues` as value):

```cs
var propertyNames = values.PropertyNames.Where(p => currentValues[p] is DbPropertyValues);
foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames) // trim
```

All complex types have `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbPropertyValues` as a value. All strings have the actual string as a value, which can be trimmed. How can I get all strings of the complex type and trim them?

Comment: IMO you should be trimming the values at the UI layer, not the DB layer.

Comment: The UI is not the only data input. There are also webservices, filereaders etc.

Comment: I accept that, but those services should also format their data correctly before sending it to the data layer.   The data layer should purely push and pull data, it should not be concerned with any formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with recursion with the help of this code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/property-values#using-dbpropertyvalues-to-access-complex-properties